# Golang Mongodb bson string slice array unmarshalling error

Tags: mongodb, go

In my MongoDB database collection, I'm storing products like so:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5e87388e622a7a973148cf15"
   },
   "tags":[
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "baz"
   ]
}
```

Which I would like to unmarshal like so:

```
type Product struct {
    Tags          []string           `bson:"tags" json:"tags"`
}
```

and when I try to retrieve it

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("correct-address"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
}
collection := client.Database("products").Collection("products")

cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    return
}
defer cursor.Close(ctx)

products := []Product{}
for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    var nextOne Product
    err := cursor.Decode(&nextOne)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    products = append(products, nextOne)
}
```

I get an error

```
cannot decode document into []string
```

Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong here?

==============
SOLVED

It turns out that I have one document in a collection that would have "tags": {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong here?

The error message `cannot decode document into []string` indicates that instead of an array, the field `tags` that you're trying to decode is a document instead. Instead of :

```js
{"tags": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}
```

You have the following:

```js
{"tags": {"foo": "bar"}}
```

I would suggest to explore the collection, perhaps there's a number of documents in the collection that have different schema than expected.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, We are one step closer. Check out my mongodb collection document I showed as the first element of my question. I have an array of strings in my document (right?). So it's a matter of go driver thinking 'tags" is a document when in fact "tags' it's an array. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It is correct for your one example, but do you have other documents in the collection? Do they all have the same structure?

Comment: Yes, and it's a document as you said. I feel so stupid now.